# Show that the vector field $\vec F=(xf(u),xg(u))$ is not conservative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, vector-analysis

I'm trying to prove that the vector field  $\vec F=(xf(u),xg(u))$ with $u=xy$ is not conservative. I suppose that there is a function $\phi$ so that $\nabla \phi= \vec F$. So I need to satisfy that: $$\frac {\partial \phi}{\partial x}= yf(u)$$ $$\frac {\partial \phi}{\partial y}= xg(u)$$ Calculating the mixed partial for each I get that: $$\frac {\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x \partial y}= f(u)+y \frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial y}$$ $$\frac {\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y \partial x}= g(u)+x \frac{\partial g(u)}{\partial x}$$ Since mixed partials are equal I have that: $$f(u)+y \frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial y}=g(u)+x \frac{\partial g(u)}{\partial x}$$ and $\frac {\partial f(u)}{\partial y}=\frac {df}{du}\frac {\partial u}{\partial y}= x\frac{df}{du}$, applying this to both sides I end up with: $$f(u)+u \frac{df}{du}=g(u)+u \frac{dg}{du}$$
This is where I'm stuck, I'm not quite sure how to get a contradiction out of this or how I can show that this statement cannot hold. Should I have taken a different approach to this problem?

Comment: Your first equations are wrong.  They should be $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}=xf(u)$, etc.

Comment: I think the vector field should be $\vec F=(yf(u),xg(u))$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In three dimensions you would check if the vector field has a non-zero curl.

Checking $F = (x f(u), x g(u), 0)$ we get
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{curl}{curl}
$$
\begin{align}
\curl F &= (0, 0, \partial_x(x g(u)) - \partial_y(x f(u))) \\
&= (0, 0, g(u) + x g'(u)y - x f'(u) x) \\
&= (0, 0, g(u) + u g'(u) - x^2 f'(u))
\end{align}
So we need $g$ and $f$ to check if that third component is non-zero.